# Focusing on the text input will expand the bottom sheet to fullscreen, how to avoid this on Android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, keyboard, bottom-sheet

Im using @gorhom/bottom-sheet and I have TextInput there, on Android focusing on textInput expands the bottom sheet to fullscreen, despite the fact that there is enough space to not expand. How can I avoid it?

```
<BottomSheetModal
    ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
    snapPoints={snapPoints}
    handleStyle={styles.handleStyle}
    enablePanDownToClose={false}
    backgroundStyle={styles.wrapper}
    onChange={onBottomSheetChanges}
>
```